# Light for Giant Quick e+ 2018

Tags: electric-bike, headlights, giant

I purchased a 2018 Giant Quick e+ for commuting.  Giant uses a modified yamaha PW-X system they have branded "syncdrive pro".  The bike is great but the headlight it comes with stinks.  I would like to drive a light with more lumens off the battery. The yamaha system uses a 36V battery that it drops down to 6V for the headlight (and presumably the tail-light).

For the 6V systems there are some options including lights from lupine SL S Yamaha E-Bike Light (500 lumen) and supernova mini2 (235 lumen).  I am getting one of of lupine lights to see if 500 Lumen is enough.

The question: I am not sure why Yamaha decided to use 6V internally, except for perhaps cost.  You can buy a 36V DC to 12V DC converter that is waterproof. IF installed the converter (and find a place for it) it seems reasonable that I could rewire the bike to use a 12V light. This would let me have a light that drives up to 1100 lumens.  Am I completely nuts or is this reasonable?

Comment: Thinking you need 1100lumens for commuting is nuts. An H4 car headlight on low beam produces 1000 lumen. A US HB1 on high bean produces 1200lumen. Car headlamps are carefully engineered to throw the light so they avoid blinding oncoming drivers, unlike most bicycle lights.

Comment: You can fit any battery-powered light you want, without having to mess around with the bike's power system.   Plus its an independent battery that won't die if the main one dies.  Downside, two batteries to charge.

Comment: Consider that you'll utterly void any warranty by messing with the wiring.

Comment: Not a duplicate, but related.  https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/51016/what-is-the-process-of-adding-a-light-to-a-yamaha-pw-equipped-ebike

Comment: And 6 watts of 6 volt AC is the standard for a dynamo-equipped bike, where 1.5W goes to the rear light and 4.5 is used by the front light.  So guessing you're in Europe where such lights are more common.

Comment: I am in the US - but clearly a bunch of e-bike tech is from the Europe / asia.

Comment: Interesting about the H4 headlights.  There are a bunch of European products that are expensive (for bike headlights) but claim to be engineered more like car headlights and not blind drivers.  These seems to be more appropriate for bike commuting than a high lumen light from say, niterider, that is less car friendly.

Comment: Personally I'd just fit and use separate battery lights, that way your lights won't decrease your range, and running out of main power won't kill your lights.  Comment, cos not really an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is that 12V is not the standard for bicycle lights. 6V is. There are a lot of very good 6V cycle lights designed for dynamo power (I don't know enough about the Yamaha/Giant wiring to know how they connect to lights). Or you can get a separate battery powered light (again, lots of very good options available).